# How can I delete algorithm list page on my document?

Tags: table-of-contents

[image: Print of this situation]

Hello everyone I am writing a master dissertation based on a model from a former student of my university, and I'm trying to delete this algorithm list page which in portuguese means "Lista de algoritmos". I can't find this part of this code on my folders and files. In case you need all the codes, I paste them all here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Do you want to comment out the code you don't need?

Comment: If you can't find it, how are we supposed to find it without any code posted? Can you please provide something we can work with to view the code? This may form part of the `.cls`, or possibly due to a package, or hardcoded somewhere at the beginning of the first included `.tex`.

Comment: https://pt.overleaf.com/latex/templates/puc-rio-thesis-and-dissertation-template/dbbybvkrrntm here is the complete template. I didn't give the file names because what I'm writing is something new. But in this link you can access all the template including this page with texts.

Comment: We don't follow external links here.  But the command `\listofalgorithms` is commonly used to insert that list.  Look for that command in your file, and if it's there, remove it.

Comment: Thank you, barbara. It worked. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Option `\algorithmsmode{none}` does what you asked.